# scan.hasNextInt waits for input on first call but not on the second call

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a method to allow the user to choose from a menu and the scan.hasNextInt waits for input the first time I call it but if I call it again the scan.hasNextInt doesn't wait for input.  The output for the code below is:
Enter a number.
1
leaving
choice = 1
Enter a 2nd number
No Input
leaving
choice = 0

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Enter a number.");
    int choice=menuChoice(3);
    System.out.println("choice = "+choice);
    System.out.println("Enter a 2nd number");
    choice=menuChoice(3);
    System.out.println("choice = "+choice);
    }

private static int menuChoice(int menuItemCount){
    Boolean inputAccepted=false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice=0;
        if(scan.hasNextInt()){
            choice=scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            inputAccepted=true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("No Input");
        }
    scan.close();
    System.out.println("leaving");
    return choice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out you should not close a scanner pointing to System.in.  When I removed the close the problem went away.